# Group object elements by category in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I have an object, which I need to turn into a list "grouped" by a child element. The current object is something like:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Productivity",
            "category": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Work",
                "color": "#fff",
                "color2": "#999"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "Focus",
            "category": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Work",
                "color": "#fff",
                "color2": "#999"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "Happiness",
            "category": {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Mood",
                "color": "#fff",
                "color2": "#999"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "Positivity",
            "category": {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Mood",
                "color": "#fff",
                "color2": "#999"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to sort and group `results` by the `category.name` key, ie:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Work",
        "color": "#fff",
        "color2": "#999",
        "packs": [
            {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "Productivity"
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "Focus"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Mood",
        "color": "#fff",
        "color2": "#999",
        "packs": [
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "Happiness"
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "Positivity"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And so on in such a way that I can loop over the result and build some sort of list.

I'm pretty sure there's a way to accomplish this with either `map` or `reduce`, but even though I've had some progress, I just can't seem to order the results in the way I need. (Pretty new to R/RN).

What I'm trying to accomplish in the long run is to be able to pass said info to a looped Component such as

```js
<CategoryList 
    key={name}
    title={name}
    results={packs}
/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why invalidate the data sample by putting a bunch of `...` in it? Nobody can use it to help you  without cleaning those up

Comment: Do the objects follow this same 'order' pattern? For example, the first name within the category has the same name as the next category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Map  with the category names as keys and new objects as values to group all the items by category.

When done grouping get the Map values and spread to array

```js
const cats = data.results.reduce((a, {id, name, category:cat})=>{
   const obj = a.get(cat.name) || {...cat, packs: []}; 
   obj.packs.push({id, name});
   return a.set(cat.name, obj);
}, new Map);

const res = [...cats.values()];

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {   max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script>
 const data={results:[{id:14,name:"Productivity",category:{id:4,name:"Work",color:"#fff",color2:"#999"}},{id:15,name:"Focus",category:{id:4,name:"Work",color:"#fff",color2:"#999"}},{id:16,name:"Happiness",category:{id:5,name:"Mood",color:"#fff",color2:"#999"}},{id:17,name:"Positivity",category:{id:5,name:"Mood",color:"#fff",color2:"#999"}}]};
</script>
```

Comment: This is a classic *"groupBy"* issue. Keep this pattern in mind for the future

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Productivity",
            "category": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Work",
                "color": "#fff",
                "color2": "#999"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "Focus",
            "category": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Work",
                "color": "#fff",
                "color2": "#999"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "Happiness",
            "category": {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Mood",
                "color": "#fff",
                "color2": "#999"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "Positivity",
            "category": {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Mood",
                "color": "#fff",
                "color2": "#999"
            }
        }
    ]
};

var processedData = [];
data['results'].forEach(result => {

    var pack = {
        'id': result['id'],
        'name': result['name']
    };
    var category = processedData.find(element => element['name'] === result['category']['name']);
    if (category) {
        category['packs'].push(pack);
    } else {
        category = {
            'name': result['category']['name'],
            'color': result['category']['color'],
            'color2': result['category']['color2'],
            'packs': [pack]
        };
        
        processedData.push(category);
    }
});

console.log(processedData);
```